# Skype bots do not work

Tags: skype, botframework

Have anybody got their bots working in Skype on iOS or Windows 10 (Desktop)?

Mine bots just doesn't work. I open chat with them, type commands and nothing happends. Same think for bots from Bots Directory. (iOS)

My desktop Skype just doesn't see any bots.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the Bot Framework, so please let me know if you're not.

If you are, here are three places to look:
1) In the Bot Framework dev portal, use the Test panel on the dashboard to make sure we can contact your bot
2) Make sure Skype is enabled and you have an "Add to Skype" button on your Skype channel
3) When you click the "Add to Skype" button, make sure Skype launches and connects to your bot

From there, you should be able to chat with your bot.

Comment: @DanDriscoll: the bot did not respond to me (3 steps are ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Skype version (Help/Check for updates).
I can see my bot from Skype for PC.

Regards

Comment: Updating skype fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the above fix was a solution since the bing "Summarize" bot is a microsoft store app that sets up the contact and behavior support in the Skype store app not the Skype desktop app.

I'm still stuck on the bot not responding to any url I provide it with a summary and have followed all the steps outlined in this support forum thread https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_featurems-skype_featwin10/summarize-bot-on-skype/350a6c79-3747-4d21-95b4-3491441b2a31 .