# Skype bot not working

Tags: c#, skype, botframework, skype-bots

1. Bot Emulator ***tested ok***
2. Bot Framework Chat Box ***tested ok***
3. Skype Integration ***tested ok***
4. Bot added to contact list ***ok***

But when I tried to chat with bot, it does not respond anything

***And when I debugged on server side, no requests made from skype to my api endpoint.***

What did I do wrong? Is there anyway I can debug the skype chatbot?

Thanks,

---

**UPDATE**: **Web embedded bot** is working, but **Skype bot** doesn't.

---

**UPDATE 2 (April 13)**: **For anyone seeking for a solution**.

I cloned my **original bot (A)** to **new one (B)**.

When I tested them, the behavior was weird.

1. I sent message to **(B)**, but I received message from **(A)** while **(B)** didn't respond
2. I sent message to **(A)**, nothing happens on both **(A)** and **(B)**

So I ended up with deleting **(A)**, and **(B)** is working mysteriously.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Prix: The code is working fine, my question is not about the code. It's about the behavior of skype bot integrating with botframework. As you seen in my question, all my testings are passed, only the skype part is broken. I'm sorry to say this but your comment is not constructive at all.

Comment: Don't blame @Prix, this question in its current form is unanswerable. Please read [ask] and provide some context.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I believe this question is answerable for someone who successfully build a bot for Skype. Maybe I was too naive for trying out my luck. The botframework just released out for a few days and not a lot of people have time to try it out. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hey @kienct89 . Is your bot B working all fine, after deleting A.??

Comment: @stranger: yes the bot B is working fine

Comment: Thanks man @kienct89

Comment: Hi @kienct89 . I tried creating bot B, and now both the bots are not replying. Bot emulator is ok

Comment: @kienct89. I am facing the exact situation as you. All 3 steps ok , created new bot B but none of the bots are replying. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @stranger the steps that I took were: create new bot in botframework portal, link the new bot to the existing api endpoint, enable the skype, and lastly delete the old bot

Comment: Thanks. I did the same. I am yet to publish the bot. I will try and update.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the status of your bot on [Skype Developer Portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/manage).
I believe that you hit Publish when you created your Skype bot, and your bot has status Pending Review. It looks like that bot will not work while the status is "Pending Review".

Do not Publish your Skype bot, in that case your Skype bot will be in Preview state and it will start working immediately. Check this [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/5SSSo6V5).

I had the same issue when I published my bot. You cannot un-publish bot, but you can delete it and create a new one. Please try it.

Comment: thanks, I just checked my bot status, it's "Preview" and I did not try to publish the bot. Tried to create another bot too, it's still not working

Comment: @kienct89 try to update your skype. check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360321/skype-bots-do-not-work

Comment: I tried to update Skype on both Desktop & Mobile version, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I finally made it work, please see my updated question. It's very weird though.